# Simulate liquid solvent mobility through a gel polymer electrolyte

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, atomistic-simulation, polymers, nudged-elastic-band

I would like to simulate a liquid solvent (such as TEGDME) embedded into a polymeric cage (such as PEGDM). **What is the most meaningful approach to estimate transport properties in such a system?**

Three options that I have in mind are:

- Using a FF typically used for liquid electrolytes such as GAFF or OPLS/A,
- Use a machine learning interatomic potential such as ANI, M3Gnet or MTP,
- Being more cautious and looking into transition state theory (such as NEB).

But I am open to others.

Thanks.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I just wanted to check up on you since it has been more than 9 months since this question was asked. Have you found an answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?

Comment: Hello @NikeDattani, I am still working on this and using TB (GFN1-xTB) within ASE

Comment: Okay, I have bumped it up to the top of the front page by editing it. Hopefully this helps the question to get an answer!

Comment: I added point 2, also pertinent to the discussion